# How to change color button onclick react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I work with buttons, and on click i need to change color button.

I have two button: favorite and stats, and onclick i need to change to custom color, for ex favorite is orange, stats blue.

How i can change color onclick?

```
<div className={classes.fotter_button}>
                    <button>
                      <FontAwesomeIcon
                        icon={faStar}
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      />
                    </button>
                    <button>
                      <FontAwesomeIcon
                        icon={faChartBar}
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      />
                    </button>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to be more specific about what you're having trouble with, and you need to show some code related to what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [favorite,setFavorite]=useState(false)
const [stats,setStats]=useState(false)

<div className={classes.fotter_button}>
                <button onClick={()=>{setFavorite(true)}} style={{backgroundColor:favorite==true?"orange":""}}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={faStar}
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  />
                </button>
                <button onClick={()=>{setStats(true)}} style={{backgroundColor:stats==true?"blue":""}}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={faChartBar}
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  />
                </button>
              </div>
```

Comment: The same result all butons on the form change colors

Comment: What do you mean? I made a change to each button individually. Did you put in the code that way?

Comment: Yes i need to change individually each color of button

Comment: so, what the problem? this code change individually each color of button. Explain yourself

Comment: This code change color all butons which i have on the form

Comment: I have few button, and each separatly i need to change color, in this aproach it's changein on click all butons color on the form

Comment: Very strange, The code has a style label for each button individually, why would it change all the buttons?

Comment: put this: <button onClick={()=>{setFavorite(true)}} style={{backgroundColor:favorite==true?"orange":""}}> only in the favorite button and this:  <button onClick={()=>{setStats(true)}} style={{backgroundColor:stats==true?"blue":""}}> to the stats button. It does not need to change all the buttons

Answer (score 2):

One way is to add state variable in your component, and use a function to change the state variable between two values (true, false). Apply the button styling based on the value of the state variable.

```
const MyToggleButton = () => {
 const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState(false);
 const toggleButton = () => setToggle(!toggle);
 
 return (
  <>
    <button style={{backgroundColor: toggle ? '#FFF' : '#000'}} onClick={toggleButton}>Click Me</button>
  </>
 );
}
```

My example is pretty generic; if possible consider using a state variable that more aptly describes your buttons two states.

Comment: Onclick all buton which i have in the form change color

Comment: @Andrew You need a state variable per button, or (like my example) create a button component, which you reuse.